# Word count program in c

Tags: c, newline, eof

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main()
{

   int nl,nc,nw,state,c;
   nl=nw=nc=0;
   state=OUT;

   while( (c=getchar()) != EOF )
   {
      ++nc;

      if(c=='\n')
          ++nl;

      if(c==' '||c=='\t'||c=='\n')
      {
          state=OUT;
      }
      else if(state==OUT)
      {
        state=IN;
        ++nw;
      }
    }
}

printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n",nw,nl,nc);
}
```

I entered
**1ctrl+z(enter)**

**ctrl+z(enter)**

[image: input and output of my program]

Please help me to explain why it didn't work for the first EOF i.e. when it first encountered ctrl+z. And how can one explain nl, nw and nc for this input?
Thnx!

Comment: The `Ctrl-Z` will only be recognised if it is the first character after a `newline`. If you `printf("%d\n",c)` in each loop, you'll see `26` appear for the untrapped `Ctrl-Z`. (But not until you enter `newline`)

Comment: And be careful, on windows `newline` is `\r\n` not just `\n`

Comment: @Weather Vane Thnx. Btw can you suggest me a reference link for explaining that property of EOF.

Comment: @Eregrith \n worked fine for other programs that  I made but not for this one. :(

Comment: @GauravJain It worked because `\r\n` contains `\n` but it would falsely recognize a single `\n` as a newline

Comment: @Eregrith Okay! Thnx for clarification. :)